# Permissions required to share a document

Tags: permissions, membership

Do you have to be a member of a site in order to be able to share documents? I have a user outside of the Teamsite, with explicit edit access inside a document set only - he cannot share those files with others and I am getting an access request to add him to the members group. Seems logical, but just wanted to check.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get this to work, the user doesn't have to be a member of the site, but the user need the permission level Manage Hierarchy on the document to be shared. In your case that applies to the Document Set.

To enable this, browse to the Document Set in question (with a user having Full Control of the Site/Web/Document Set) and select the Manage-tab at the top. Select Permissions.

[image]

Next, select Grant Permission button in the ribbon and add the user who should be able to share documents in the Document Set. Select the Show Option text in the lower part of the modal dialog, and select "Manage Hierarchy" for the user in question. Click Share and your done.

[image]